# Unreadable text on VirtualBox running on Kali

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

Installing virtualbox is fine, the boxes also run fine, it's just that the text in the vbox manager is white and so is the background, making it unreadable.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axjjU.png)

I'm running Kali that's released in 2019, some of the machine info:

```
root@kali:~# lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2020.2
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

```
root@kali:~# cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2020.2"
VERSION_ID="2020.2"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
```

My desktop environment is xfce, the default the comes with kali, with a Kali-dark theme, changing into other dark themes still creates this problem.

Comment: I have the same issue with the real kali. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution is to use a dark theme in vbox

```
virtualbox -style fusion
```

The text stays white but the background turns dark